# In or On fits in the sentence?

Tags: word-usage

I saw this sentence from a news article. Is it ok to use 'on' here? If yes, are there any differences compared with 'in'?

> "We’ll continue to work closely with our partners in the international community **in** identifying, tracking and countering any cyber threats.”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using either *on* or *in* would generally convey the same meaning to readers. For some readers, depending on their background, *on* would sound better while *in* would sound better to others.

I think here *in* sounds better because of the preceding clause:

> We’ll continue to work closely with our partners in the international community...

This sets out that the speaker will be working with someone on a task.

If they had been speaking of the task instead of placing the emphasis on their collaboration they might instead have said

> "We’ll continue to work on identifying, tracking and countering any cyber threats.”

In this construction *on* fits better, addressing the task rather than any collaboration.

I think the key indicator for using *in* instead of *on* is the use of *closely* because using *closely in* sounds better than *closely on*.

> We’ll continue to work closely [with someone] in identifying, tracking and countering any cyber threats.

Comment: So, will it be considered to be wrong by using 'on' in this sentence?